# Multi row table with merged columns and long text

Tags: tables, formatting, multicolumn, overleaf

I've been struggling with making this table in Latex. Can anyone please help? I am writing a paper but it takes ages to move my tables into Overleaf.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please add some clarifications to your question: Where are the merged columns and what did you try so far? A simple `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXl}` (needs the `tabularx` package) should work. For the horizontal lines, take a look at the `booktabs` package.

Comment: True, there are no merged columns. I struggle with making lines invisible - the ones below WORD. I tried random things and I do not even remember them but they left the lines between the cells messed up... I am not a person who codes - sorry for my vague question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ll>{\raggedright}Xr}
    \toprule
\textbf{Label 1}& \textbf{Label 2}&\textbf{Label 3}& $N$\\
\midrule
WORD &Short phrase&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 2
\\
 &Short phrase&
New Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
& 3
\\
\midrule
WORD &Short phrase&
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
&4
\\
 &Short phrase&
New Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
Description on several lines. Description on several lines.
&5
\\
\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: David thank you so much! This is so awesome. Such a speedy reply. I can keep writing the paper. It would have taken me one day to figure this table out. I'm so grateful!